# When I visit Django /admin via a Rewritten URL I am redirected to 127.0.0.1 rather than the correct url

Tags: django, apache, mod-proxy, gunicorn

I haven't used Apache with Django very much, normally using nginx, gunicorn and a unix socket instead.

When experimenting with Apache, mod_proxy and Django, I've been trying to pass all requests to a gunicorn backend, listening on 127.0.0.1:8998.

I've achieved this using a Rewrite ... [P] (see below), however, this works fine for the default URL, when I go to http://foo.bar.com/admin I get redirected to 127.0.0.1/admin, which clearly doesn't work remotely. Is this a setup possible to achieve via an htaccess file, and what do I need to do/look at to fix it up?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     (.*) http://localhost:8998/$1 [P]
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure a rewriterule is what you want? aren't you trying reverse proxy?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what [P] does, as I thought that was mod_rewrite's method of talking to proxies? The other issue is that this may not be achievable without root access, but thought I'd ask in case there was a method I was unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it working with http://localhost and http://localhost/ ?

try this:

```
RewriteRule     ^/(.*) http://localhost:8998/$1 [P]
```

I have recently researched what you are trying to achive and ended up with this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass        /static/ http://example.com:8080/static/
ProxyPassReverse /static/ http://example.com:8080/static/
```

I am passing all static path requests to nginx in this case, but it may work with gunicorn for you.

Of course, you need to enable apache2 module proxy.

Comment: Can you do that within the htaccess? I thought that ProxyPass etc. directives had to be done at the server level?

Comment: I am doing it in a virtualhost conf, though a quick search on google looks both positive and problems when used in an htaccess file.